# The Rails way to creating in-app links to non-trivial routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, routes

I've been digging through [routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) documentation and seem to have only uncovered half of the necessary info needed for this one.

If I create a route which looks like:

```
match 'attendances/new/:class_date/:student_id'
```

I'm afraid I'm completely unclear on how to create an appropriate `link_to` incantation which is capable of fulfilling the above.

For example, I seem to have no problems creating this URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/attendances/new?class_date=2012-05-07&student_id=5
```

but I've yet to find appropriate docs which explains how to create this:

```
http://localhost:3000/attendances/new/2012-05-07/5
```

Could someone provide a helpful example and/or a link to docs which discusses how to do this?

I realize that trying to use `link_to` might be completely inappropriate here. And I realize I could munge together some code which will craft the appropriate links, but I suspect that doing so will completely miss some better, Ruby-on-Rails way to doing this.

Edit: Corrected proposed `match` route, above.

Edit 2: Going on "mu is too short"'s suggestion, here's what my routes.rb now looks like:

```
NTA::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :students

  resources :libraries

  resources :year_end_reviews

  resources :notes

  resources :ranktests

  resources :attendances

  match 'attendances/new/:class_date/:student_id', :as => :add_attendance

  resources :ranks

  get "home/index"

  root :to => "home#index"

end
```

and here's the relevant view:

```
<% today = Date.today %>
<% first_of_month = today.beginning_of_month %>
<% last_of_month = today.end_of_month %>
<% date_a = first_of_month.step(last_of_month, 1).to_a %>
<h2><%= today.strftime("%B %Y") %></h2>

<table id="fixedcolDT">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <% date_a.each do |d| %>
      <th><%= d.day %></th>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<% @students.each do |s| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= s.revfullname %></td>
    <% date_a.each do |d| %>
      <% student_attend_date = Attendance.find_by_student_id_and_class_date(s.id, d) %>
        <% if student_attend_date.nil? %>
          <td><%= link_to "--", add_attendance_path(d, s.id) %></td>
        <% else %>
          <td><%= student_attend_date.class_hours %></td>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</tbody>
</table>
```

and here's what I get back after the initial reload (before trying to restart WEBrick):

```
ArgumentError

missing :controller
Rails.root: /Users/jim/Documents/rails/NTA.new

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
config/routes.rb:15:in `block in <top (required)>'
config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
This error occurred while loading the following files:
   /Users/jim/Documents/rails/NTA.new/config/routes.rb
```

I'll pastebin what I got back after my failed attempt to restart WEBrick, if interested.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you want to give the route a name so that you'll get the appropriate helper methods:

```
match ':attendances/:new/:class_date/:student_id' => 'controller#method', :as => :route_name
```

That will generate two methods that you can use to build the URL:

1. `route_name_path`: The path for the URL, no scheme, hostname, ...
2. `route_name_url`: The full URL including scheme, hostname, ...

Those methods will use their parameters for the route's parameter values in order so you could say:

```
<%= link_to 'Pancakes!', route_name_path(att, status, date, id) %>
```

and `:attendances` would be `att`, `:new` would be `status`, etc. Alternatively, you could pass a Hash to the method and use the parameter names directly:

```
<%= link_to 'Pancakes!', route_name_url(
    :attendances => att,
    :new         => status,
    :class_date  => date,
    :student_id  => id
) %>
```

Comment: great detailled answer, as usual... +1 :)

Comment: Ran into some trouble, and it seems my proposed `match` rule wasn't quite what I intended. Will edit, then share what happened next.

Comment: So after trying to implement the suggestion, I hit reload on the page. It threw a `missing :controller` ArgumentError. So I tried to restart WEBrick, and it spewed in technicolor (then exited), basically the verbose version of the noted ArgumentError. Perhaps it would be better if I added more detail to my original question.

Comment: @caffecaldo: You need `match ':attendences/...' => 'controller#method'` where `controller` is the controller and `method` is the name of the controller method.